# add derby.jar database to jdk 1.8.0_191

Tags: netbeans, java-8, derby

The Derby Database is not included in the jdk1.8.0_191 We are using Windows 7 64 bit. We are using Netbeans 8.2 configured to use jdk1.8.0_162 and with this jdk we can embed the derby database for JavaFX applications. Our question is can we install the derby database in the jdk1.8.0_191 with the steps listed below?
[Down Load Link](https://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.14.2.0.cgi)

We downloaded **lib distribution - contains only the jar files for Derby.**
and unzip the file. Next we created a folder in jdk1.8.0_191 named "db" with a sub folder named "lib" and will copy the unziped files to this sub folder lib

We notice that the files in the db sub folder named "bin" are missing as is the sub folder bin. Yes we are being conservative here and asking for help because we do not want to mess up or older JavaFX projects. Step by Step directions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to put Derby inside your JDK? You can just put the Derby distribution elsewhere and reference it via CLASSPATH, right?

Comment: @BryanPendleton I guess because the JDK 1.8.0_162 had the derby.jar in the db sub folder lib and one web site I looked at suggested the idea OK can I function without the files in the bin folder

Comment: Yes the scripts in the bin directory are just some simple wrappers which set things like JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH and then launch Java to run Derby. All of the actual Derby implementation is in the jar files.

Comment: @BryanPendleton OK Thank You Will give it a try bed time where I live